# Delete/Edite a client message in private Chat with Telegram Bots

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

In private chat with a bot (a user and a Bot), is it possible to edit/delete user messages? I am creating a Telegram Bot for registration. As a registration step, the users insert their password, and for security considerations, I want to replace it with stars or delete it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as calling `deleteMessage` with `chat_id` and `message_id`

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

EDIT:

As @mohamad-mehdi-rajaei mentioned in his comment, this method seems to be just to delete bot sent message, not user sent message.

The only solution I can imaging is to provide a numeric password inline keyboard to user and ask him/her to enter password by pushing your numeric inline keyboard buttons. In this way nothing be logged in client, and you manage user input as callback data in server side.

Bad thing with this approach is that user became limited to numeric password.

Comment: I've already tried this method, but it just can be used to delete the bot messages. When I try to delete a user's message, I encounter an error: 400 : Bad Request

Comment: Sorry, it seems you are right!
The only solution I can imaging is to provide a numeric password inline keyboard. Bad thing with this approach is that user became limited to numeric password.

Answer (score 0):

[Bot API 4.2 changelog (updated April 14, 2019)](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#april-14-2019):

> The method [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) can now be used to delete messages sent by a
>   user to the bot in private chats within 48 hours.

Since the method signature is not changed, any wrapper/framework (like python-telegram-bot) support this operation by now.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to provide s a solution - https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/328 .

Basically, there's a deleteMessage endpoint you can use - https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteMessages, passing it the message ID. So when you get the message (with it's ID), just delete it.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteMessages is telegram api method, not telegram bot api method.

Comment: I can get message IDs, but how should I call the above-mentioned method? Can I use c# WebRequest? In case of Yes, what is the full url being used in the request?